# Script in cron not executing

Tags: cron, raspbian

I've been trying to make an internet speed monitor (because our internet connection sucks, and I wanted to be able to show to our ISP that they're giving sh*tty service) by following this http://makezine.com/projects/send-ticket-isp-when-your-internet-drops/

SO far I've been only succesfull on making the script itself. When I test the script by typing in ./speedtest-cron.sh in the terminal window it runs perfectly. But when I add it in the crontab like so

```
40 * * * * ./speedtest-cron.sh
```

it does nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't you mind to specify the full path to the script?

Comment: I believe you should provide the full path of your script, please check.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where the file actually is. Where is it created? I created it using sudo nano

Comment: I tried making a new script file on the desktop. As suggestted, I provided the whole path the line in the crontab now reads 40 * * * * /home/pi/Desktop/speedtest-cron.sh.
It still doesn't do anything.

Comment: Are you sure that cron service is run? What does your script do? How do you check if it runs or not?